# Input element and CSS not working

Tags: html, css

I've been fighting with an input element and CSS. I am not very good in design.
I am trying to create like that:

[image]

My input is inside a form that is inside a

:

```
<li>
<FORM class="searchform" NAME="Search" ACTION="./index.cfm?P=128" METHOD=POST >
    <INPUT type="text" name=search value="" STYLE="color: #676767; background-color: #282828; line-height: 18px" size="10" maxlength="40"  Placeholder="search">
    <INPUT class="search_button" TYPE=SUBMIT NAME="SubmitButton1" VALUE="Search" ID="SubmitButton1">
</FORM></li>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);
body, html {height: 100%; margin: 0; font-size:16px;}
body {font-family: Arial;}
header {width: 100%; background-image: url('img/top-bg.png'); background-repeat: repeat-x; background-color: #dfebf2; position: fixed; height: 70px; z-index:2;}
aside {width: 270px; min-height: 100%; position: fixed; background-color: #dfebf2; left: 0; max-height: 100%; overflow-y: auto; /* border-right: 1px solid #bdcada; */}
section {top: 70px; left: 270px; position: absolute;}
h3 {font-family: 'Montserrat', Arial; text-transform: uppercase;font-size:15px;}
select {width: 230px; height: 34px; border: 1px solid #bdcada; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; margin: 10px 0 0 0; padding-left: 8px; border-radius: 3px;}
table, th, td {border: 1px solid #bdcada;}

input.search_button {
    color: black;
    line-height: 23px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', Arial;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 20em;
    height: 2em; 
}

.height-112px {height: 112px;}
#logo-box {float: left; margin-left: 20px; margin-top:10px; width: 250px;}
#mobile-menu-icon, #mobile-profile-icon {display:none;}
#top-nav {position: absolute; width: 100%; background-color: #282828; min-height: 42px; top: 70px; color: #fff;}
.top-nav-links {list-style-type: none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; padding-left: 20px; padding-right:20px; line-height: 42px;}
.top-nav-links li {font-weight: bold; display: inline; margin-right: 15px; font-size: 10px; text-transform: uppercase; font-family: 'Montserrat', Arial;}
.top-nav-links a {color: #676767; text-decoration: none;}
.top-nav-links a:hover {color: #fff;}
.active-top a {color: #fff;}
#details-box {padding: 30px 20px 30px 20px; border-bottom: 1px solid #bdcada;}
#height-5px {height: 5px;}
.details-1 {font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; color: #1072ad;}
.details-2 {font-style: italic; font-size: 12px; color: #9ca6b6; margin-left: 10px;}
.details-3 {font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px; color: #000; margin-left: 10px;}
#details-box a {text-decoration: none;}
.logout {font-size: 11px; color: red;}
#property-box {padding: 25px 20px 30px 20px;}
.blue-nav-title {font-family: 'Montserrat', Arial; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px; color: #1072ad; text-transform: uppercase;}
.list-title {height: 42px; background-image: url('img/top-bg.png'); padding: 0 20px 0 20px; border-bottom: 1px solid #0b5987; line-height: 42px; font-family: 'Montserrat', Arial; font-size: 12px; color: #fff; text-transform: uppercase;}
.nav-links {list-style-type: none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;}
.nav-links li {font-size: 12px; color: #6e7888; padding-left: 20px; line-height: 50px; border-bottom: 1px solid #bdcada;}
.nav-links a {text-decoration: none; color: #6e7888;}
.nav-links li:before {content: "â–º "; font-size: 7px; color: #157cb8; vertical-align: top; margin-right: 8px;}
.nav-links a:hover {text-decoration: none; color: #000;}
.active {background: #fff;}
#content {margin-left: 50px; margin-top: 92px;}



table {font-size: 12px; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; overflow-y:scroll; height:300px; display:block;}
table td, th {padding: 10px;}
table tr:hover {background: #f0f6f9;}

.table-b {font-size: 12px; border-collapse: collapse; width: AUTO; HEIGHT: AUTO; display:block;}
.table-b td, th {padding: 10px;}
.table-b tr:hover {background: #f0f6f9;}

.table-a {font-size: 12px; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; }
.table-a td, th {padding: 10px;}
.table-a tr:hover {background: #f0f6f9;}


form.searchform {display: inline-block;}
#login {width: 240px; border: 1px solid #bdcada; border-radius: 3px; padding: 30px; font-size: 12px;}
.input {width: 230px; height: 30px; border: 1px solid #bdcada; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 8px; border-radius: 3px;}

.divTable{
  display:table;         
  width:auto;         
  background-color:#eee;         
  border:1px solid  #666666;         
  border-spacing:5px;
}
.divRow{
  display:table-row;
  width:auto;
  clear:both;
  background-color:#ccc;  
}
.divCell{
  float:left;
  display:table-column;         
  width:100px;         
border-left: 2px solid #fff;
}


/* columns float left while they fit â€“ some spacing in there too between columns*/
#column {width:48%;float:left;padding-right:20px;}

/*the table will always fill up the space of the column â€“ column starts at 50% of the screen width so two can fit */
table {width:100%;margin-bottom:20px}

/* responsive breakpoint â€“ at 1000px screen, the tables no longer fit side by side, so they auto-fit top-to-bottom, so make them each full width */
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
                #column {width:100%;}


@media only screen
and (max-device-width : 768px) {
    body, html {width:100%; margin: 0; font-size:14px;}
    header {position:initial; height:auto;}
    aside {width:100%; position:initial; min-height:initial;}
    section {position:initial;}
    select {width: 100%; height:auto; padding:8px; font-size: inherit;}

    .height-112px {height: auto;}
    #logo-box {float: none; margin:0px; width: 100%}
    #logo-img {margin: 10px 10px 5px 10px;}
    #mobile-menu-icon, #mobile-profile-icon {display:block; float:right; height:45px; width:45px; margin: 12px 12px 5px 0px;}
    #top-nav {position: initial; display:none; clear:both; border-bottom: 1px solid #bdcada; background-color: inherit; width: 100%; min-height: inherit;}
    .top-nav-links li {display:block; width:100%; font-size: 16px; line-height:36px;}
    .top-nav-links li:first-child {padding-top:10px;}
    .top-nav-links li:last-child {padding-bottom:10px;}
    .top-nav-links a {color: #000;}
    .active-top a {color: #1067a6;}
    #details-box {display:none; padding: 20px;}
    .details-1, .details-2, .details-3, .logout {font-size: inherit;}
    #property-box {padding: 20px;}
    .blue-nav-title {font-family: 'Montserrat', Arial; font-weight: bold; font-size:inherit; color: #1072ad; text-transform: uppercase;}
    .list-title {font-size:inherit;}
    .list-title:after {content: "+"; font-weight: bold; font-size: 18px; float:right;}
    .opened:after {content: "-"; font-weight: bold; font-size: 18px; float:right;}
    .nav-links {display: none;}
    .nav-links li {font-size: inherit;}
    .nav-links li:before {content: "â–º "; font-size: 11px;}
    #content {margin:0; padding:15px;}
    table {font-size:inherit;}
    table tr.odd {background: #eeeeee;}
    table th {font-weight:normal; text-align:left;}
    #login {width: 100%; padding:20px; max-width:400px; margin:0 auto; box-sizing: border-box;-moz-box-sizing: border-box;-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; font-size: inherit;}
    .input {width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;-moz-box-sizing: border-box;-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; font-size: inherit;}
}

@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 200px)
and (max-device-width : 319px) {
    #mobile-menu-icon, #mobile-profile-icon {display:block; float:right; height:40px; width:40px; margin: 13px 10px 5px 0px;}
}

@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 425px)
and (max-device-width : 600px) {
    body, html {width:100%; margin: 0; font-size:15px;}
}

@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 600px)
and (max-device-width : 768px) {
    body, html {width:100%; margin: 0; font-size:16px;}

}
```

My search button is aligned to my li.
My result is like that:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Please remove all irrelevant css and html and leave only the smallest amount of code that still reproduces the problem but does not require us to understand whole your project

Comment: I am not sure , But try `vertical-align:bottom`  in `.search_button` class , You can also try , `vertical-align:baseline` or `vertical-align:middle`

Comment: remove the line-height on the search_button as well, you can also try to reove all styles from it, since your desired example looks like the default browser button

Comment: How can I remove all styles for only one input?

Comment: just remove the styles that belong to search button like this .search_button { }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

style your search button like this

```
input.search_button {
  color: black;

  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', Arial;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 2px;

}
```

**If you want to  style one input then add an `id` and style that id as stated**

Snippet

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);
 body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
}
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}
header {
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url('img/top-bg.png');
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-color: #dfebf2;
  position: fixed;
  height: 70px;
  z-index: 2;
}
aside {
  width: 270px;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #dfebf2;
  left: 0;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  /* border-right: 1px solid #bdcada; */
}
section {
  top: 70px;
  left: 270px;
  position: absolute;
}
h3 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', Arial;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 15px;
}
select {
  width: 230px;
  height: 34px;
  border: 1px solid #bdcada;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  padding-left: 8px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #bdcada;
}
input.search_button {
  color: black;

  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', Arial;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 2px;
 
}
.height-112px {
  height: 112px;
}
#logo-box {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 250px;
}

#mobile-menu-icon,
#mobile-profile-icon {
  display: none;
}
#top-nav {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #282828;
  min-height: 42px;
  top: 70px;
  color: #fff;
}
.top-nav-links {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  line-height: 42px;
}
.top-nav-links li {
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 15px;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', Arial;
}
.top-nav-links a {
  color: #676767;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.top-nav-links a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
.active-top a {
  color: #fff;
}
#details-box {
  padding: 30px 20px 30px 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bdcada;
}
#height-5px {
  height: 5px;
}
.details-1 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #1072ad;
}
.details-2 {
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #9ca6b6;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.details-3 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #000;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
#details-box a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.logout {
  font-size: 11px;
  color: red;
}
#property-box {
  padding: 25px 20px 30px 20px;
}
.blue-nav-title {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #1072ad;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.list-title {
  height: 42px;
  background-image: url('img/top-bg.png');
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #0b5987;
  line-height: 42px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.nav-links {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
.nav-links li {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #6e7888;
  padding-left: 20px;
  line-height: 50px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bdcada;
}
.nav-links a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #6e7888;
}
.nav-links li:before {
  content: "â–º ";
  font-size: 7px;
  color: #157cb8;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-right: 8px;
}
.nav-links a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}
.active {
  background: #fff;
}
#content {
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 92px;
}
table {
  font-size: 12px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 300px;
  display: block;
}
table td,
th {
  padding: 10px;
}
table tr:hover {
  background: #f0f6f9;
}
.table-b {
  font-size: 12px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: AUTO;
  HEIGHT: AUTO;
  display: block;
}
.table-b td,
th {
  padding: 10px;
}
.table-b tr:hover {
  background: #f0f6f9;
}
.table-a {
  font-size: 12px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
.table-a td,
th {
  padding: 10px;
}
.table-a tr:hover {
  background: #f0f6f9;
}
form.searchform {
  display: inline-block;
}
#login {
  width: 240px;
  border: 1px solid #bdcada;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 30px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.input {
  width: 230px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #bdcada;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 8px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.divTable {
  display: table;
  width: auto;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #666666;
  border-spacing: 5px;
}
.divRow {
  display: table-row;
  width: auto;
  clear: both;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.divCell {
  float: left;
  display: table-column;
  width: 100px;
  border-left: 2px solid #fff;
}
/* columns float left while they fit â€“ some spacing in there too between columns*/

#column {
  width: 48%;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
/*the table will always fill up the space of the column â€“ column starts at 50% of the screen width so two can fit */

table {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px
}
/* responsive breakpoint â€“ at 1000px screen, the tables no longer fit side by side, so they auto-fit top-to-bottom, so make them each full width */

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  #column {
    width: 100%;
  }
  @media only screen and (max-device-width: 768px) {
    body, html {
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      font-size: 14px;
    }
    header {
      position: initial;
      height: auto;
    }
    aside {
      width: 100%;
      position: initial;
      min-height: initial;
    }
    section {
      position: initial;
    }
    select {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      padding: 8px;
      font-size: inherit;
    }
    .height-112px {
      height: auto;
    }
    #logo-box {
      float: none;
      margin: 0px;
      width: 100%
    }
    #logo-img {
      margin: 10px 10px 5px 10px;
    }
    #mobile-menu-icon,
    #mobile-profile-icon {
      display: block;
      float: right;
      height: 45px;
      width: 45px;
      margin: 12px 12px 5px 0px;
    }
    #top-nav {
      position: initial;
      display: none;
      clear: both;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #bdcada;
      background-color: inherit;
      width: 100%;
      min-height: inherit;
    }
    .top-nav-links li {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      font-size: 16px;
      line-height: 36px;
    }
    .top-nav-links li:first-child {
      padding-top: 10px;
    }
    .top-nav-links li:last-child {
      padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .top-nav-links a {
      color: #000;
    }
    .active-top a {
      color: #1067a6;
    }
    #details-box {
      display: none;
      padding: 20px;
    }
    .details-1,
    .details-2,
    .details-3,
    .logout {
      font-size: inherit;
    }
    #property-box {
      padding: 20px;
    }
    .blue-nav-title {
      font-family: 'Montserrat', Arial;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: inherit;
      color: #1072ad;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    .list-title {
      font-size: inherit;
    }
    .list-title:after {
      content: "+";
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 18px;
      float: right;
    }
    .opened:after {
      content: "-";
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 18px;
      float: right;
    }
    .nav-links {
      display: none;
    }
    .nav-links li {
      font-size: inherit;
    }
    .nav-links li:before {
      content: "â–º ";
      font-size: 11px;
    }
    #content {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 15px;
    }
    table {
      font-size: inherit;
    }
    table tr.odd {
      background: #eeeeee;
    }
    table th {
      font-weight: normal;
      text-align: left;
    }
    #login {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 20px;
      max-width: 400px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      font-size: inherit;
    }
    .input {
      width: 100%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      font-size: inherit;
    }
  }
  @media only screen and (min-device-width: 200px) and (max-device-width: 319px) {
    #mobile-menu-icon, #mobile-profile-icon {
      display: block;
      float: right;
      height: 40px;
      width: 40px;
      margin: 13px 10px 5px 0px;
    }
  }
  @media only screen and (min-device-width: 425px) and (max-device-width: 600px) {
    body, html {
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      font-size: 15px;
    }
  }
  @media only screen and (min-device-width: 600px) and (max-device-width: 768px) {
    body, html {
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      font-size: 16px;
    }
  }
  body{
  background:black}
```

```html
<li>
  <FORM class="searchform" NAME="Search" ACTION="./index.cfm?P=128" METHOD=POST>
    <INPUT type="text" name=search value="" STYLE="color: #676767; background-color: #282828; line-height: 18px" size="10" maxlength="40" Placeholder="search">
    <INPUT class="search_button" TYPE=SUBMIT NAME="SubmitButton1" VALUE="Search" ID="SubmitButton1">
  </FORM>
</li>
```

Comment: It makes the search button the same height of the form. I mean the whole black nav bar

Comment: just add an height rule that that button and notice how that navbar adjust its height to the button..also you should notice that vertical align middle if you add that vertical rule...one issue with your piece of code was applying that  line-height rule on your button